# simple onListItemClick() arguments

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm kind of new here so please bear with me if this seems like a stupid question.
I'm currently using onListItemClick to retrieve the id of the selected ListItem.
I'm quite confused about the difference between the int position and long id argument.
Is it the same? Could someone kindly explain it please. Thank you in advanced.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    int _id = (int)c.getLong(0);
    //int _id = (int) id;
    String word_id = Integer.toString(_id);

    Toast.makeText(this, word_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I was planning to use as simple button instead of the above method but I didn't know how to retrieve the ListView for the Activity.

Comment: The position is the position of the view in the ListView (the first entry has the position 0). The id is to identify the data row of the position). The id may be the row id of a row from a database for example. By this you can identify what information are at this position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l   The ListView where the click happened
v   The view that was clicked within the ListView
position    The position of the view in the list
id  The row id of the item that was clicked
```

Comment: So if I was printing random entries from a db and try to retrieve a particular row I should be using id instead of position? Thank you!

Comment: position you need to use. position will give you the entry clicked in the list. so it will give you value from the 0 to total cursor count. you need to fetch value from the cursor at the position which Poistion parameter give.